# After entering the field value, this value is not returned to the method

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I have written my project with C# and Kendo. My problem is that the kendoTextBox value is not passed

```js
                        
                        
                   $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#serialNo').data('kendoTextBox').value({
                            dataValueField: function (e) {
                                report.selectedCar = e.dataItem;
                                if (report.selectedCar && report.selectedCar.Id > 0) {
                                    report._createReportGrid();
                                    console.log('serialNo')
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        });
```

```html
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="serialNo">@Html.Raw(Localizer["The Last 6 Digits Of The Chassis Number"])</label>
            </div>
            <div class="k-edit-field">
                <input name="serialNo" id="serialNo" class="k-textbox" value="" autocomplete="off" required />
                <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="serialNo"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```